User-defined type assertion guard for builder results in data field being null
I am trying to make a builder that allows for both chaining and type assertions.
Chaining is working fine.
Assertions, however, are not updating the data correctly.
type BuilderSchema = {
    [k in string]:{
        data: ReadonlyArray<string>
    }
}
type BuilderData<T extends BuilderSchema>={
    [k in keyof T]:{
        value:T[k]["data"][number]
    }|null
}
//type helper for blank schema data
type NulledOutBuilderData<T extends BuilderSchema>={
    [k in keyof T]: null
}
interface Builder<Schema extends BuilderSchema,Data extends BuilderData<Schema>=NulledOutBuilderData<Schema>>{
    _data:Data,
    //chaining
    setData: <
    const K extends keyof Schema,
     const Value extends Exclude<BuilderData<Schema>[K],null>["value"]|null
     >(key:K,value:Value)=>Builder<Schema,UpdatedBuilderData<Schema,Data,K,Value>>
    //assertions
    setAndAssertData: <
    const K extends keyof Schema,
     const Value extends Exclude<BuilderData<Schema>[K],null>["value"]|null
     >(key:K,value:Value)=>asserts this is Builder<Schema,UpdatedBuilderData<Schema,Data,K,Value>>
}
type UpdatedBuilderData<
    Schema extends BuilderSchema, 
    CurrentData extends BuilderData<BuilderSchema>,
    Key extends keyof Schema,
    NewValue extends Exclude<BuilderData<Schema>[Key],null>["value"] | null
>= {
        [k in keyof Schema & keyof CurrentData]:
             k extends Key
                ? NewValue extends null
                    ? NewValue
                    :{
                        value: NewValue
                    }
            :CurrentData[k]
}

const schema = {
    prop1:{
        data:[
            "hello",
            "world"
        ]
    },
    prop2:{
        data:["foo","bar","baz"]
    }
} as const satisfies BuilderSchema

//function that returns a builder of the specified schema
declare function createBuilder<const Schema extends BuilderSchema>(schema:Schema):Builder<Schema>

//chaining. no problems
let builder1 = createBuilder(schema)
builder1.setData("prop1","world").setData("prop2","baz").setData("prop1","hello")


//i want to smash my keyboard
let builder2:Builder<typeof schema> = createBuilder(schema)
builder2.setAndAssertData("prop1","world")
builder2._data
//          ^? never?


Playground link
Please help. I would greatly prefer to not have to use void as I want the types to be clear as to what is and isn't defined for better intellisense. Chaining is "okay", but if I want to, say, get data to determine whether or not a field should be modified, an extra variable would have to be allocated which just feels like jank DX. Void is not the end of the world, but still results in weak typing.

• This code takes up a lot of vertical space that it probably doesn't need; ideally it should all fit on a single screen at once to help people understand it. • k is not a conventional type parameter name; please use K or something conventional. Shorter type parameter names are preferred over longer ones especially for complicated types. • [k in string] is largely unconventional, either [K in string] or [k: string] would be better, preferably the latter since it's just an index signature, not a meaningful mapped type.

(see prev comment) UpdatedBuilderData is complicated. Can you explain what it's supposed to be doing? Specifically, is there some sense in which UpdatedBuilderData<S, D, K, V> is ever likely to be a subtype of D? If not then what you're doing is not a proper narrowing and an assertion function will never work.

(see prev comment) Yeah, this would have been really nice with some verbal description of what you think is happening at each stage. As far as I can tell: before the assertion you want builder2._data.prop1 to be null, and afterwards you want it to be "world" or something? Is that right? Then it's 100% impossible. It's not a narrowing, it's a mutation. The TS type system doesn't model mutation. So, uh, your question seems to be, uh, "please help". Right now the only answer I could give is "abandon assertions" or "do real narrowings". Does that fully address it or is something missing?
